# D3 Parse Date "2013-07-11T00:00:00" for line graph

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js

How do I parse an array of dates like this: "2013-07-11T00:00:00", into something useable for a line graph? The graph will stretch back a full year.

I'm trying to create a dynamic graph like the one in the "Plotting a chart" section on [this page](http://dev.markitondemand.com/#doc_interactivechart).

It would be great if I could have the tick marks like that as well (Apr '13).

I'm currently using the following function in JavaScript:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").parse;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing "Z" in your format *specifier* which makes your parser return `null` for the dates you give to it. Here's an example that works:

```
var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").parse;
parse('2013-07-11T00:00:00'); // Thu Jul 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

You can use [d3 time scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) to display time-based axes with appropriate tick marks.

**Edit:**

I guess I misunderstood your question... here's another take which (hopefully) explains the usage of time scales and date formatting:

```
var scale = d3.time.scale(),
    axis = d3.svg.axis(),
    // Assuming you have your data as strings:
    data = ['2013-07-11T00:00:00', '2013-08-11T00:00:00', ...],
    range = [0, 500], // size of chart
    domain = d3.extent(data, function (d) { // generate the data extent (min,max)
        return new Date(d); // use Date instances for values
    });

// Configure the scale with domain and range:
scale.domain(domain).range(range);

// Use the above scale for the axis:    
axis.scale(scale)
    // Print the dates in "Mmm dd" format:
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %d'));

// Render the axis in your svg node:
svg.call(axis);
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think OP wants "Mmm 'yy" which would be `.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b \'%y'))` or `.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b '%y"))` if the escape character bugs ya ;)

Comment: @jshanley oh, indeed! Failed to notice it. Good catch.